# drop down select field stays null Livewire

Tags: dropdown, laravel-livewire

I'm trying out Livewire for the first time. The drop-down is populated from the database. Similar codes works for text fields, but fails with drop-down select fields.
Edit: The form is inside a bootstrap modal
Code is as below: The livewire component (leads-form.blade)

```
 <div class="modal-content">
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit">
            @csrf
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <label for="role">Client</label>
                <select  class="error validate" wire:ignore id="client_id" wire:model="client_id">
                    <option disabled value="&nbsp;">Client</option>
                    @foreach($clients as $client)
                        <option value="{{$client->id}}"> {{$client->clientname}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col m12 s12">
                <input id="contactperson" type="text" name="contactperson" wire:model="contactperson" />
                @error('contactperson') <span class="error"><small>{{ $message }}</small></span> @enderror
                <label for="contactperson">Contact Person</label>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <button class="btn cyan waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit">Add
                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

Next Livewire leads class is as a below:

```
class LeadsForm extends Component
{

public $contactperson;
public $client_id;





public function submit()
{


    Lead::create([
        'client_id' => $this->client_id,
        'contactperson' => $this->contactperson,
       
    ]);

    Alert::toast('Client created successfully', 'success');
    return $this->redirectRoute('leads.index');
}




public function render()
{
    $clients = Client::all();
  

    return view('livewire.leads-form',[
        'clients'=>$clients,
   

    ]);
}
```

}

I'm using the laravel debugbar, and it shows the array client_id field as null.

Comment: Are you using any kind of js library to generate select?

Comment: @Qudratxo'jaMusayev I'm using materialize https://materializecss.com/select.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wire:ignore in the select element, that avoid produce any Livewire event that can be wrapped to backend

```
<select  class="error validate" wire:ignore id="client_id" wire:model="client_id">
 <option disabled value="&nbsp;">Client</option>
 @foreach($clients as $client)
   <option value="{{$client->id}}"> {{$client->clientname}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Removed, but I still get the same result

Comment: That form is inside a div container?

Comment: Yes, let me update the code to include the div's

Comment: And what's the issue??? inside the submit method put a dd($this->client_id) and when you select one and click button something dump?

Comment: Yeah! The Client dump is correct, the dropdown gets populated. I select a client, the dropdown greys out and laravel debug bar shows null on client_id as if I never selected a client

Comment: so, it's solve or remain the issue on submit?